# Animating two views with different start times and same finish time

Tags: ios, core-animation, caanimation

I am trying to find a way to animate two views in this way: they will start animating at different times but end their animations at the same time.

Think of a horse race where one horse starts after the other, but they both reach the finish line at the same time.

Its not a grouped animation. Also, how to I tell an animation to wait until a certain time to start?

Does anyone have any pointers on how to do this?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[UIView animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:]`

Example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
    // first animation code here
}];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f delay:0.5f options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn animations:^{         
    // second animation code here
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```